# Changing value of non-cascading parameter causes refresh of all parameters

Tags: reporting-services

We have a SSRS report that has 17 parameters, 10 are cascading (dependent upon one another), 7 aren't (independent).

The very first parameter in the report shouldn't affect any of the other parameters.  It has three string values that are hard coded into the parameter.  None of the parameters (or datasets) that follow it use refer to it.  It is only used to show/hide sections of the report.

When the report is running (in VS or from Report Manager) and you change the value of the first parameter, it seems to take a minute or two for the other parameters to become available.  I believe it’s trying to refresh the other parameters, but it shouldn't be.

Does anyone know if there is a way to stop that unnecessary refresh?

Comment: try moving the non-dependent parameters to the end of the list, you can do so using the up and down arrow from the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that works, but the users want that parameter at the top.  Is there any other workaround?

Comment: are they in the query also?